# ASP.Net e C# - envio de e-mail automático

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, task

No site que assumi de um cliente, desenvolvido em ASP.Net com C#, existem colaboradores cadastrados com uma data de admissão definida. O cadastro desses colaboradores está em uma tabela de banco SQL Server 2008.

Eu precisava criar alguma coisa (talvez um task) que conferisse se existem usuários com 45 dias desde a sua data admissão. Possivelmente uma consulta SELECT no banco. Se existir, um e-mail automático é enviado pro(s) devido(s) usuário(s) avisando que eles devem preencher uma autoavaliação.

Como eu posso fazer isso? O ASP.Net tem alguma coisa nesse sentido?

Comment: Você pode criar um projeto do tipo "Serviço" no C# e instalar no servidor para que rode rotinas de tempos em tempos. Ou simplemente colocar uma tarefa agendada no servidor para ser executada todos os dias em horários específicos, e dentro desse software você faz o envio de emails e consultas no banco.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Como eu posso fazer isso? O ASP.Net tem alguma coisa nesse sentido?

[Sim, o Hangfire](http://hangfire.io).

Para agendar uma tarefa para executar todo dia:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => MeuMetodoDeAtualizacao(), 
    Cron.Daily);
```

[O Hangfire tem pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire/).

Comment: Boa, não sabia que tinha esse recurso, da para usar com webforms ou só mvc?

Comment: Dá pra usar com Webforms sim.

Comment: Cara tem como eu eu especificar um horario? Tipo eu precisava que todos os dias as 8:00 da manhã meu servidor executasse uma tarefa, Mas não achei como fazer isso com o Hangfire